# Playing audio through more than one audio out device

Tags: audio

When I partially plug my earphones into my audio in port (just the nub), audio is able to run through both my speakers and earphones. The earphones only take in mono audio though. So my question is twofold, am I able to have audio come out through more than one device. And the second question is why does my plugging in part of the earphones allow me to hear mono-audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the model of computer:

1. Many computers use a **hardware switch mechanism** in the stereo mini-phone jack to disable the internal speaker, as in the diagram below (only one channel is shown for simplicity). If you plug in the earphone only *partway*, then you haven't activated the switch, but, of the three connections, the two metal bands and the metal tip), only two are making contact (i.e. tip and first band) so you hear only monophonic sound.

[image: Switched jack]

For these computers, the simplest solution is to use an [external (amplified) speaker with its own earphone jack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008VF6F) or a [line splitter](http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Speaker-and-Headphone-Splitte) (links for reference purpose only).

2. Some computers offer a **software switch mechanism**, e.g. the Windows *Sound Control Panel*.

[image: Windows Sound CPL]

In that case, sound can be directed to speakers and/or earphones by right-clicking the device and selecting it. However, if only one device can be selected, the splitter cable still is needed.

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer the second question, but for the first, if you put a splitter in the microphone jack of your computer, you can listen with headphones, and also listen with external speakers.  (Not sure if that addresses your question.)